# Can't obtain Azure Oauth V2 access token in C#

Tags: c#, azure, active-directory, azure-webapps

I'm trying to obtain an access token from an Azure Web App...C# MVC app. Here is the code I'm using.

```
    public string GetToken()
    {
        string authority = string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, AuthEndPoint, tenantId);

        var credential = new ClientCredential(clientId, clientSecret);
        AuthenticationContext authContext = new AuthenticationContext(authority,true);

        var token = authContext.AcquireTokenAsync(AzureResourceID, credential).Result.AccessToken;
        return token.ToString();
    }
```

If I strip V2.0 off the end of the authority string, the app will successfully return a V1.0 access token.

How do I get a V2.0 token?

Comment: What's the value of `AzureResourceID` in your code?

Comment: I'm trying to connect to an Azure SQL database from an Azure Web App, using delegated access based on the Azure AD user logged into the Azure Web App.

Comment: AzureResourceID="https://database.windows.net/"

Comment: Any other concerns? If not, please [accept it as answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).

Answer (score 0):

You could not get the v2.0 access token from the resource `https://database.windows.net`, the version of the token is decided by the resource, not the client.

Access tokens are created based on the `audience` of the token, in your case `https://database.windows.net`, its related enterprise application is `Azure SQL Database` whose `Application ID` is `022907d3-0f1b-48f7-badc-1ba6abab6d66`, it is the resource your client request token for, the [`accessTokenAcceptedVersion`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/reference-app-manifest#accesstokenacceptedversion-attribute) of it is `null`, if the value is `null`, this parameter defaults to `1`, it means you can just get the v1.0 token from this resource, no matter v1.0 or v2.0 endpoint you used in the authority.

See - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/access-tokens

[image]

Comment: So, I've done some more digging and I now realise that the issue isn't the token version. It has nothing to that. I used the quick-start from Azure App Service, when I created the app service and enabled authentication to login with Azure Active Directory. This does force authentication successfully, but I now suspect that, when I use the code above to get the access token, it's generating a new one and it's not using the authenticated user from the login. If I was a betting man, I'd say it's probably using the anonymous user.

Comment: I know the issue isn't with the user I'm using to login. It's the admin account for everything. There is a login and user in the db associated with it in the DB and I've enabled delegation to Azure SQL for the app in the App registration in Azure AD.

Comment: I had thought that, because I was originally authenticating with a V2 authentication (that's what the quick start builds), I would need a V2 access token and that was what I thought was tripping me up. The error that I'm trying to fix is "Login failed for user '<token-identified principal>'" when I use the token to connect to an azure db. I thought the problem was with the token version, but now I'm pretty sure that I'm barking up the wrong tree. I think the problem is with the user signature on the token I get.